# iPhone signal strength

Tags: iphone

I know this question has been floated, but there are not any answers.  In Objective C, is there a way to return signal strength?

Comment: Did you get answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple does not allow developers direct access to the low-level wireless API functions. It is possible to include some of these functions in your application (see the [iphone-wireless project](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/) for example) but your application will not be accepted for inclusion in the iTunes store.

Previously some applications were allowed to do this (WiFiFoFum for example) but these applications have been removed from the store for using private APIs.

Comment: Thank you, I had not considered going rouge.

Comment: Going rouge is not bad, depending on your complexion.  But going rogue is more fun!  :-)

Comment: Did not get the answer I was looking for, but learned a new word :D

Answer (score 3):

It's not documented API I believe, but you may git clone VAFieldTest in Github. Search `int result = CTGetSignalStrength();` in this app.
See the selected answer here: [Measuring cellular signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954389/programatically-measuring-carriers-signal-strength-in-iphone-device)

If you just want to see the signal strength, call `*3001#12345#*` in the Phone app and it will shown in the status bar.

http://socialtimes.com/find-your-iphones-signal-strength-using-the-hidden-field-test-mode_b4690