# How to display info about the Cell Towers nearby?

Tags: ios, ios5, cell, core-telephony

I am looking for a way to display info about the cell towers located nearby.
I know I have to use the CoreTelephony framework.
I do not need to deploy it, so I do not care about Apple approve.

Please help me to find the appropriate way for doing it.
I am using iOS 5.0.1 on iPhone 4S.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567708/getting-cell-tower-information-in-an-ios-application you'll find some nice links to private API _documentation_ there. Guess that would be a way to start your research.

Comment: That does not work on iPhone 4S iOS 5.. I guess it is a problem that has never been solved yet