# How to display custom signal strength display on iOS devices

Tags: cocoa-touch

Our app can't use status bar and we want to display a custom signal strength on iOS devices? Is that possible?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567708/getting-cell-tower-information-in-an-ios-application

Comment: I just need to display signal strength. The other post was asking for stuff that's more involved, such as cell tower distance.  Also, the signal strength could be Wifi as well.

Comment: I understand, that's why I didn't call it a duplicate :) but now that I look, it might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959567/iphone-signal-strength

Comment: Thanks for digging these up. The post is two years old, have some of these changed? The second answer also contradicted the selected answer.