# Fetch location from carrier not lat/lon

Tags: ios, ios5, geolocation, location

Most people will remember the old Nokia phones, which showed your current district (cell tower) you are connected to.

Is this information available on iOS? if so, how to fetch this info?

SO I mean when in New York it would for example return "fulton" as the district...

Answer (score 1):

You don't get access to the cell tower information as you described on iOS, however you can always use the CoreLocation framework (MapKit if you also want backward compatibility with iOS 5.0 for some reason) to do a reverse geocode and get as much detail as available.

For iOS 7.0, you use the CLGeocoder object.

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    // Iterate through available placemarks
}];
```

The location parameter is a CLLocation object you would have received or created for the user's location.
For reverse geocode requests the array in the completion handler will only contain a single placemark. The various properties and their corresponding real-world relations for a placemark object can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLPlacemark/locality)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already have this implemented. The reason I would like the cell tower info is because GPS might work, but wifi/3g not. That way the geolocation would not work. My only option would be to keep track of the unresolved locations and then resolve when connection comes back. Though this might become a lot. So thanks for the answer, but it doesn't help me further..

Comment: AFAIK, the CLLocationManager API works without a cell phone signal. Apple simply provides the cellular triangulation as CLLocationManager's last resort.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that we can get from the cell tower is from  core telephone framework

```
Obtaining Information About the Cellular Service Provider
   allowsVOIP  property
   carrierName  property
   isoCountryCode  property
   mobileCountryCode  property
   mobileNetworkCode  property
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html

Comment: Yes, I have read that information, I was hoping that it was somehow possible anyway.

Comment: Why dont you want to use CoreTelephony to get the information?

Answer (score 0):

Apple currently does not provide any public API that reveals cell tower meta data. From the looks of how they approach telephony API design, I don't see this becoming a feature in the future, either.

Check out: [Getting cell tower information in an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567708/getting-cell-tower-information-in-an-ios-application)