# Measuring cellular signal strength

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am developing a non-appstore app for iOS. I want to read the cellular signal strength in my code.

I know Apple doesn't provide any API by which we can achieve this.

Is there any private API that can be used to achieve this? I have gone through the various threads regarding this issue but could not find any relevant info.

It is completely possible because there is an [app in the app-store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/baralarm/id364878555?mt=8) for detecting the carrier's signal strength.

Comment: Does the value coming from VAFieldTest is accurate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I briefly looked at the VAFieldTest project located at [Github](https://github.com/valexa/VAFieldTest).

There seems to be  `getSignalStrength()` and `register_notification()` functions in Classes/VAFieldTestViewController.m that might be interesting to you as they call into `CoreTelephony.framework`.

I am pretty confident that some of the used calls are undocumented in the [CoreTelephony framework documentation from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html) and therefore private - any app in the AppStore must have slipped passed inspection.

Comment: @Niels Castle How can I convert the signal strength that I got using  VAFieldTest application to dBm?

Comment: Follow the link to Github and you'll be able to interact directly with Vlad, the maintainer of VAFieldTest.

Comment: Is it possible to get other parameters as well : RSCP (signal level), 
SC (Scrambling Code) and EcNo (Signal To Noise Ratio)?

Comment: The project crashes almost instantly on iOS 9.

Comment: Any idea how OpenSignal does their signal strength measurement ? They show the technology and signal strength on their home screen (tested on iOS 10), and the value is very accurate.

Comment: Signal to Noise ratio is SNR and is different from EcNo. For Wcdma 3G,SNR is EbNo, which normally is a positive value as opposed to EcNo.

Answer (score 15):

Get signalStreght IOS9:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];  
NSArray *subviews = [[[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"]     valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];  
NSString *dataNetworkItemView = nil;  
     for (id subview in subviews) {  
   if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView") class]])  
   {  
        dataNetworkItemView = subview;  
        break;  
    }  
 }  
int signalStrength = [[dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"signalStrengthRaw"] intValue];  
NSLog(@"signal %d", signalStrength);
```

Comment: Works on iOS9 devices (not on simulators)

Comment: Is this a private API https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView.h UIKit is listed as public, but it seems like a private value.

Comment: Follow up. I built a small demo of this, created an app in itunes connect, and validated the store submission app archive. This isn't foolproof, but ostensibly the private API error would have been triggered?

Comment: Crashes on iOS12 device, unfortunately

Answer (score 12):

It is not very hard.

1. Link CoreTelephony.framework in your Xcode project
2. Add the following lines where you need it

Code:

```
int CTGetSignalStrength(); // private method (not in the header) of Core Telephony

- (void)aScanMethod
{
    NSLog(@"%d", CTGetSignalStrength()); // or do what you want
}
```

And you are done.

**Update May 2016**

Apple removed this opportunity.

Comment: it runs on iOS 9.1 , but value 0 is returned, no matter I use LTE or Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 6):

To get signal streght in iOS 9 or above in Swift 3, without using the private API from CoreTelephony - `CTGetSignalStrength()`. Just scouring the statusBar view.

```
func getSignalStrength() -> Int {

    let application = UIApplication.shared
    let statusBarView = application.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
    let foregroundView = statusBarView.value(forKey: "foregroundView") as! UIView
    let foregroundViewSubviews = foregroundView.subviews

    var dataNetworkItemView:UIView!

    for subview in foregroundViewSubviews {
        if subview.isKind(of: NSClassFromString("UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView")!) {
            dataNetworkItemView = subview
            break
        } else {
            return 0 //NO SERVICE
        }
    }

    return dataNetworkItemView.value(forKey: "signalStrengthBars") as! Int

}
```

**Attention**: If the status bar is hidden, the key "statusBar" will return nil.

Comment: It hurts my soul, but it meets the requirements: it works and it doesn't use any private APIs.  Thank you!

Comment: @EliotGillum does apple approves it?

Comment: key used does not exists in ios 10

Comment: It uses private API : "value(forKey: "signalStrengthBars")"

Comment: @user100 yes, I've already submitted 2 apps in App Store with success .

Comment: @user100 the key "statusBar" does existis, but you status bar could be hidden.

Comment: Any fix for IOS 11

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but apparently this is now a method of `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` instead of a global/static function.

The return type is `id`, so I think you get either a `NSDictionary` (as the `_cachedSignalStrength` ivar implies) or an `NSNumber` (as the old function implies).

```
id signalStrength = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new] signalStrength];
```

This changed in iOS 8.3, as you can see from the [commit](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/e913fc81fdf47444ceafe3eaa7eeb4b73e61322a/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h#L60).

Note that this is still not documented! So if your app will go in the App Store, take your precautions.

Comment: `signalStrength` returns `null` in iOS 9

Comment: I am trying to get the cellular signal strength for iOS 9 but as mentioned above its returning 0. Using UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView does not work in background mode so it is of no use as i need to get signal strength in background. Please let me know if anybody is able to get the values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's Lucas' answer converted to Xamarin, and tested on iOS 10.2.1:

```
var application = UIApplication.SharedApplication;
var statusBarView = application.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
var foregroundView = statusBarView.ValueForKey(new NSString("foregroundView")) as UIView;

UIView dataNetworkItemView = null;
foreach (UIView subview in foregroundView.Subviews)
{
    if ("UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView" == subview.Class.Name)
    {
        dataNetworkItemView = subview;
        break;
    }
}
if (null == dataNetworkItemView)
    return false; //NO SERVICE

int bars = ((NSNumber)dataNetworkItemView.ValueForKey(new NSString("signalStrengthBars"))).Int32Value;
```