# How to get signal strength on obj-c?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm stuck on how to get the signal strength using Objective-C.

I'm referring to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCfyKfIwSDQ&feature=player_embedded).  Many people say accomplishing that task is impossible, since Apple hasn't opened the API, but how did the person on the video do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it ***is*** possible but it's not a public method and therefore you won't be able to get it on the app store.  The app in the video was just a demo version.

Check out this duplicate question:  [Measuring cellular signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954389/programatically-measuring-carriers-signal-strength-in-iphone-device)

Comment: tx for reply Michael, very apprciate that, and this is tottaly what im looking for.
btw i can built the app since i missed the VoiceService framework, is there anyway so i get the framework?

Thanks.