# How BarAlarm iOS app is made?

Tags: objective-c, ios, private, signals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [programatically measuring carrier's signal strength in iPhone device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954389/programatically-measuring-carriers-signal-strength-in-iphone-device)

I'm creating an application for iOS that should be able get signal strength from the device. I know that using private APIs this is possible, but I want to publish this app in app store in the future, so I can't use any private APIs in this case.

There is one app in the Store that is able to show signal strength level in bars, and that would be enough for me, too. The application is this one:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/baralarm/id364878555?mt=8

My problem is that I can't find any way to implement this kind of functionality without using private APIs, but as Apple has accepted BarAlarm to the Store, it should be possible.

In a nutshell: How iOS application can get signal strength, event at the level of bars, without using private APIs?

Comment: From my point of view it's not a duplicate; I know how this is possible with the private API, but how BarAlarm is able to do that while Apple did accept it to the store?