# Collecting RSRP values in iOS

Tags: ios, lte, umts

I am working on a new iOS app where I need to report the `LTE` or `UMTS RSRP` level in certain times together with position (`lat`/`long`). I am using `CLLocationCoordinate2D` for the position portion, but how do I find the `RSRP` value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4954389/1166266