# Complex line warns: AnyObject is not a subtype of NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, compiler-errors, nsobject

I'm trying to convert the following code into Swift 3. Its purpose is to print the cellular signal strength to the console. The StackOverflow post this came from can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34389611/1500134).

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *subviews = [[[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"]     valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
NSString *dataNetworkItemView = nil;
for (id subview in subviews) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView") class]])
    {
        dataNetworkItemView = subview;
        break;
    }
}
int signalStrength = [[dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"signalStrengthRaw"] intValue];
NSLog(@"signal %d", signalStrength);
```

And, after my own attempts (swift is new to me), some online converters, and Xcode's automatic conversion from Swift 2.2 to 3, i'm stuck with two issues. Here is the current problematic code:

```
let app = UIApplication.shared
let subviews: NSArray = (((app.value(forKey: "statusBar"))! as AnyObject).value(forKey: "foregroundView"))!.subviews
var dataNetworkItemView: NSString?
for subview in subviews {
    if (subview as AnyObject).isKind(of: NSClassFromString("UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView")!) {
        dataNetworkItemView = subview as? String as NSString?
        break
    }
}
let signalStrength = Int(((dataNetworkItemView!.value(forKey: "signalStrengthRaw") as! String) as NSString ?? "0").intValue)
print("signal \(signalStrength)")
```

The second line (let subviews: ...) throws the error:

`'(AnyObject)' is not a subtype of 'NSObject'`

and the second to last line (let signalStrength = ...) throws the following warning:

`Left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type 'NSString' so the right side is never used`

The second issue makes more sense to me than the first, but how can I go about fixing the actual error? I'm not intending to be spoon-fed code but rather am trying to figure out why the error exists and what would satisfy the error and produce the desired results. Thanks :)

Comment: You're saying "Swift 2.2"? Do you have valid Swift 2.2 code you could go off on? While the code is easy to fix I would suggest ripping it out and starting new converting line by line on your own. Also note, the code seems to be using symbols that are not publicly documented. This might be problematic if you plan to submit this to the App Store.

Comment: @Arthur My Swift 2.2 code wasn't valid either but it had different error messages. I'm trying to go line by line from objective c but these two lines are still giving me trouble. And the post I reference has a user who said they successfully got past review with an app that only had this in it, meaning the private symbols were well exposed, so... idk.

Answer (score 0):

idk if it works for you. but i was having same issue and it works for me
try using **NSArray** instead of **AnyObject**

```
let subviews: NSArray = (((app.value(forKey: "statusBar"))! as NSArray).value(forKey: "foregroundView"))!.subviews
var dataNetworkItemView: NSString?
```