# Get signal strength with CoreTelephony, swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am building an app where i would like to get the signal strength. 
I have read that it should be possible via CoreTelephony, and earlier it was via getSignalStrength(). This does not seem to be possible in swift 3.

I have seen this post [Measuring cellular signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954389/measuring-cellular-signal-strength) but can not get it to work.

Is there an equivalent way to do this in swift 3?

Comment: This functionality has never been officially documented. There were various techniques that used to work but they used private APIs that no longer work in iOS 10.  You could try using the signal strength view which is one of the answers in the duplicate; there is no indication in the answer whether it still works in iOS 10.

Comment: I have seen the post you refer to, but i can't get it to work in swift 3 - which is why i created this new post :(

Comment: Then you probably can't do it. It has never been officially supported.