# Measuring received signal strength with swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am building an non-app store application where i would like to get the signal strength. I have searched in earlier threads, but it seems like most solutions is not possible in swift 3 anymore - e.g. CoreTelephony's getSignalStrength().

I have read this post [Measuring cellular signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954389/measuring-cellular-signal-strength) but would unlike last answer very much like to have the actual received signal strength, and not just a number for how many bars it translates to