# How to check signal strength using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I've seen the question asked but not answered to anyone's satisfaction.  My app makes many network calls.  I'd like to check signal strength and if it falls below a threshold, alert the user that the app won't function at that level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measuring cellular signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954389/measuring-cellular-signal-strength)

Comment: As per the duplicate....."I am pretty confident that some of the used calls are undocumented in the CoreTelephony framework documentation from Apple and therefore private - any app in the AppStore must have slipped passed inspection."

Comment: The answer suggests screen scraping the status bar... but also makes clear:  If the status bar is hidden, the key "statusBar" will return nil.  In my case the status bar will be hidden.