# Get network accuracy (Cellular + WiFi) on Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

Is it possible to retrieve more precise information in cordova concerning the network ?

I have already tested : **cordova-plugin-network-information**, **cordova-plugin-networkinterface** and **cordova-plugin-sim** plugins, but with anyone these plugins I can't get the precision of the cellular network or the WiFi.

In fact, I seek to make reportings about the accuracy/power of the surrounding networks of the smartphone (WiFi & Cellular)

If you know a method (or idea) that works, ideally for iOS & Android, I'm ready :)

Thanks for your help!

++

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any existing cordova-plugin for this but you can always create your own plugin for such specific use-cases. [SignalStrength](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html) looks like a promising way to go, probably the whole [Android telephony](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html) section will be of interest for you.

You can take the network-information cordova plugin and check how they managed to send continous updates on the cellular type and then do it in a similar way for the signal strength.

For the iOS signal-strength part you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955390/6184203) answer on SO.