# xcode - Network Strength in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-telephony, mobile-development

I know that it is not really going to help me out, but still I have some doubts related to "CTGetSignalStrength()" method of Core Telephony framework. What I know about this method is:

1. It is an undocumented method.
2. It belongs to a Private API.
3. If I use this method, App store will reject my application.
4. Also, I read that there is no public API to get the Signal Strength in iOS.

My reason to pick this topic up again because all the other answers are atleast 2 years old.

And also, I have seen some applications on App store which really tells about the cellular/Wifi Strength(Like Dr.Wifi-something).

If its not possible to get the signal Strength, how those applications are getting it? Or there is some other way now through which we can get the network Strength. I would really appreciate if someone can enlighten me on this. Thank you.

**EDIT** : I have checked that question before, the one in the comment, but please see that :
 1. The answer is really old.
 2. In the comments, you can see someone asked "How OpenSignal is doing there signal strength measurement?" and there is no reply to that.
 3. Every opportunity to get signal strength is either removed in the updated iOS version, or giving null or 0 as output.

So I am not really sure if there is no solution present for the problem or, the solution is not yet updated to that question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measuring cellular signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954389/measuring-cellular-signal-strength)

Answer (score 0):

from iOS 9 and later it seems you can get wifi signal strength look at this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspothelper
But also you must get entitlement. From Apple docs

> The com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper entitlement is required
> in order to use NEHotspotHelper. To request this entitlement, complete
> the questionnaire at
>
> https://developer.apple.com/contact/network-extension.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to answer this, I will definitely check it up. Just one more thing, How to get the cellular network strength?

Comment: @Mohd Naved Sorry, but I didn't found public api for cellular network, but however you can look here, maybe you will got some luck :) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension