# How Identify the cellular or mobile network signal strength

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a simple code that shows the network status as the below image:

[image]

related to the below code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:android_device_info/android_device_info.dart'; 

import '../widgets/row_item.dart';

class NetworkTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NetworkTabState createState() => _NetworkTabState();
}

class _NetworkTabState extends State<NetworkTab> {
  var data = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    var data = {};

    final memory = await AndroidDeviceInfo().getNetworkInfo();
    final display = await AndroidDeviceInfo().getNfcInfo();
    var sim = await AndroidDeviceInfo().getSimInfo();

    data.addAll(memory);
    data.addAll(display);
    data.addAll(sim);

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        this.data = data;
      });
    }

    var permission =
        await PermissionHandler().checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.phone);
    if (permission == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      var permissions =
          await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.phone]);
      if (permissions[PermissionGroup.phone] == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        sim = await AndroidDeviceInfo().getSimInfo();
        data.addAll(sim);
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            this.data = data;
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (data.isEmpty) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Divider(),
          RowItem('Network Available', '${data['isNetworkAvailable']}'),
          RowItem('Network', '${data['networkType']}'),
          RowItem('iPv4 Address', '${data['iPv4Address']}'),
          RowItem('iPv6 Address', '${data['iPv6Address']}'),
          RowItem('WiFi Enabled', '${data['isWifiEnabled']}'),
          RowItem('WiFi SSID', '${data['wifiSSID']}'),
          RowItem('WiFi BSSID', '${data['wifiBSSID']}'),
          RowItem('WiFi Speed', '${data['wifiLinkSpeed']}'),
          RowItem('Signal strength(Cellular)', '???'),
          RowItem('WiFi MAC', '${data['wifiMAC']}'),
          Divider(),
          RowItem('NFC Present', '${data['isNfcPresent']}'),
          RowItem('NFC Enabled', '${data['isNfcEnabled']}'),
          Divider(),
          RowItem('IMSI', '${data['imsi']}'),
          RowItem('Serial', '${data['serial']}'),
          RowItem('Country', '${data['country']}'),
          RowItem('Carrier', '${data['carrier']}'),
          RowItem('SIM Locked', '${data['isSimNetworkLocked']}'),
         RowItem('activeMultiSimInfo', '${data['activeMultiSimInfo']}'),
          RowItem('Multi SIM', '${data['isMultiSim']}'),
          RowItem('Active SIM(s)', '${data['numberOfActiveSim']}'),
          Divider(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So now I have two types of Network:

- Wifi
- Cellular(2G/3G/4G)

So I need now to figure the signal strength like the shown in the below figure if the network type is `Cellular`:

[image]

Is there's any plugin that shows the value of signal strength, or I can use connectivity plugin to figure it....

If I use connectivity plugin how can I figure the `Signal strength` value through this plugin..

I hope this would be clear enough..

Answer (score 0):

use  [internet_speed_test](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_speed_test) plugin. I got exact internet speed using the same. I have displayed signal strength on Text widget, by using following code

```
final internetSpeedTest = InternetSpeedTest();
    
internetSpeedTest.startDownloadTesting(
              onDone: (double transferRate, SpeedUnit unit) {
                // TODO: Change UI
              },
              onProgress: (double percent, double transferRate, SpeedUnit unit) {
                // TODO: Change UI
    
                setState(() {
                  if (unit == SpeedUnit.Kbps) {
                    speed = transferRate.toStringAsPrecision(3) + ' Kbps';
                  }
                  if (unit == SpeedUnit.Mbps) {
                    speed = transferRate.toStringAsPrecision(3) + ' Mbps';
                  }
                });
              },
              onError: (String errorMessage, String speedTestError) {
                // TODO: Show toast error
              },
              //  testServer: fetchLatestAppVersionCodeUri.toString(),
              //Your test server URL goes here,
            );
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't apply.  Searching for signal strength, not bandwidth...

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent plugin for that here: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_internet_signal

Unfortunately it only supports Android.

And from those 2 posts, it seems Apple removed APIs to access that information:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/112601
[Measuring cellular signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954389/measuring-cellular-signal-strength)