# Is there a way to know the strength of a WiFI signal on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to show WiFi networks table sorted by their signal?
It sounds very unlikely that apple will let us do such a thing but I'll ask that anyway.

Thanks

Comment: No you can check only if connection is available or not but you can't get signal strenth

Comment: Please see the following article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959567/iphone-signal-strength

Comment: I dont think you can do that without some type of private API

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018110/accessing-using-the-mobilewifi-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can check only if connection is available or not but you can't get signal strenth.For more detail you can go with this link
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959567/iphone-signal-strength)